# MVC Identity Custom Token and Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-identity

I have UserManager and am making a custom ApplicationUserManager.  How do I incorporate a custom token provider and validator for something completely different than validating your account?

The way I want to use this is when the parts manager creates an order, it sends an email to all office managers.  The managers all need to have a custom token and in this email, it has two buttons, a reject button and an approve button.  Each will have a link back to my website, flagging the order appropriately.

I could generate a random string or numbers and save it to the database, one for each approve and reject, and each manager would get basically the same email with different userIDs in the callback url to tell the who approved or rejected the order.

I would rather create a function in the ApplicationUserManager somewhat like the .GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync function and then .ConfirmEmailAsync, but for .GenerateOrderApprovalTokenAsync and .GenerateOrderRejectionTokenAsync.  That way each user will have a completely different token that will expire after x amount of hours.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction.  All the custom tokens I see online are all for validating your account.